# How to include references and bibliography list using bookdown word_document_2?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, pandoc-citeproc

I am trying to include bibliographic citations and a list of references in a MS Word file generated with Rmarkdown bookdown. However, I get the following message in the RMarkdown terminal: **“pandoc-citeproc: reference Rbase not found”**, where Rbase is the id of the cited material.

Although the MS Word file is generated, the citation is not recognised as such in the introduction (instead it shows “[@Rbase]”, nor the list of references is displayed [(see image attached)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ISWBXx6N4W3kT7Vvyi5rp3GDSUvKf7oO/view?usp=sharing).

This is my .Rmd file:

```r
---
title: "Report with Rmarkdown"
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2:
  bibliography: references.bib
---

# Introduction

This is my introduction [@Rbase].

# References
```

This is the content of the file references.bib (UTF-8), which is located in the same folder as the .Rmd file.

```
@manual{Rbase,
title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
author = {{R Core Team}},
organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
address = {Vienna, Austria},
year = {2016},
url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
}
```

Can anyone provide any insight on how to make the citation and list of references visible?

Thank you very much in advance,
Carmen

Comment: Have you tried removing the leading spaces from '  bibliography: references.bib'? See first example yaml in https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html where there is no indent for the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you so much. You nailed it. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by 'markdly' in the comments: Removal of the leading spaces before 'bibliography: references.bib' in .Rmd file.